# How to create an inner border (stroke) in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, vector-graphics

I created a shape in Inkscape and set the border width to `1px`.
The actual size is `100px` however with a border it's `102px`.

How can I set an **inner border** on the object, not outer? When using *Photoshop*, the type
is selectable (*inner*, *outer* or *center* border), however in *Inkscape* there isn't this option.

Comment: For users who understand SVG code, there's a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778568/how-to-make-an-inset-drop-shadow-in-svg ("How to make an inset drop shadow in SVG").

Answer (score 27):

Inkscape doesn't support changing the type of stroke on an object, however there's
other ways to create the inner border or blur that you need.

One simple method is making a copy of the shape, with no fill and the chosen border (stroke).
This copy is given a [*clipping path*](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip-Clipping.html) so the extra (outer) part of its stroke can't be seen outside the
original shape. The path used to clip it is a second, unchanged copy of the original shape,
which doesn't appear as a normal/regular object.
To make sure these copies change when the original is edited, they can
each be a [*linked offset*](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html#Paths-Offsets) - also allowing them to be moved inside the original shape.

1. create the shape and select it (`F1`)
2. create a [linked offset](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html#Paths-Offsets) copy, which appears on top of it (`Ctrl+Alt+J` or `Path` menu)
3. change the stroke (border) width to **2x** what you need or set its offset
   magnitude/radius to move it to the inner edge of the outer shape border
   - with its node handle or XML attribute *(built-in editor, units are pt not px)*
4. give this shape *no fill* and the chosen border colour - fill and stroke in object menu
5. create a second *linked offset* copy of the original shape, leave it unchanged
6. select this shape *and* the copy from step 3 (hold `Shift` key, drag mouse)
   - make sure that this shape is on top (z-order) - see manual page linked above
7. *set clip* - use the `Object → Clip → Set` menu item

Then you should have a finished inner border.

Comment: How do I select pasted and stroke shape? Nothing happens with Shift.

Comment: @Dima See the **above answer**, that I've updated - you need to drag the mouse or click other objects when pressing the `Shift` key. Also, the following tutorial page, that can also be seen in the application, could be useful: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html.

Comment: That's amazingly non-intuitive, but works perfectly.

Comment: Hello year ago me, who forgot about this entirely.

Comment: Mind the issues with printing of clipped objects: [Clipped Objects Not Printing](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/clipped-objects-not-printing).

Answer (score 20):

An alternative workflow to the one presented by @cristian-ciupitu would be this:

1. Create (or select) an object or a path with no fill. If you want, you can already set the stroke width (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), or fix this later.
2. Duplicate (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) the object/path. This will create a duplicate on top of the original.
3. Send the duplicate Lower (`Object`→`Lower`, or <kbd>Page Down</kbd>), so that you can...
4. ... choose Select (`arrow` on the toolbar, or <kbd>F1</kbd>) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the object/path. As the "Lowered" duplicate was already selected, this will select the two identical objects/paths on top of each other. The status line at the bottom of the window should confirm this.
5. Now choose `Object` → `Clip` → `Set`.

Voila! Inner border!

You can now adjust the inner border width (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) if you want. Set the stroke width to twice your desired inner border width, as half of the stroke width will be clipped invisible.

If you think steps 3 and 4 are confusing, just drag around the two objects/paths to select them both, clip them as in step 5, and adjust the stroke width as desired. Works as well, but hey, clicking is cooler ;)

Comment: Essentially you're doing the same thing, but I find your directions easier to understand.

Comment: Mind the issues with printing of clipped objects: [Clipped Objects Not Printing](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/clipped-objects-not-printing).

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if by "border" you mean "stroke" but it appears SVG standards don't allow for inner/outer strokes, and thus neither does Inkscape. It seems a common thing to do is fake it by duplicating the object and shrinking/growing it so you get the border you want. Though I don't imagine this would work as well for an inner border as an outer border.

[Inkscape bug: Inner/outer/center stroke placement](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170401)

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn

Answer (score 4):

- Select the stroke and Path -> Stroke to path, now your stroke becomes a "shape"
- Use Path -> Division to divide the shape into inner and outer parts.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this goal, my work around is to first click the option on the toolbar to turn OFF that "Scaling artwork scales stroke"

[image: Scaling artwork scales stroke icon]

Next, set your desired stroke width.

Finally, change the size of the object back to what you wanted it to be.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to do this just because of pure perfectionism, I found out it's not possible, then settled with this solution: if I draw a 100x100 filled square and want it to have a 10 px border, with the square's size remaining 100x100, I just set the stroke size as needed, then set the object's size back to 100x100. Sure, the stroke size changes but I live with that.